# how to change a view's x, y positions slowly in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

there is an ImageView i have. when screen gets touch then my imageview should move upward on screen. Actually its a jump. when i touch to screen my character jumps. but it happens instantly. it instantly going to -100 in y positions. i want to make it slowly, like slowly jump how can i do that?

anakarakter = my ImageView

that method(Anakarakter) works in a timer, handler.

```
    public void Anakarakter ()
    {
        gameScreen.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getX() < gameScreen.getWidth() / 2)
                    {
                        anakarakter.startAnimation(left);
                    }
                    if(event.getX() > gameScreen.getWidth() / 2)
                    {
                        anakarakter.startAnimation(right);
                    }
                    anakarakter.setX(event.getX() - anakarakter.getWidth() / 2);
                    anakarakter.setY(anakarakter.getY() - anakarakter.getHeight() - 50);
                }
                if(anakarakter.getX() < 0 )
                {
                    anakarakter.setX(0);
                }
                if(anakarakter.getX() > gameScreen.getWidth() - anakarakter.getWidth())
                {
                    anakarakter.setX(gameScreen.getWidth() - anakarakter.getWidth());
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: and there is one more thing i want to ask. in translate animation is my imageview's positions(x, y) uptading while animation happens?

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63332826/edit) to add more detail instead of commenting it.

Comment: where is translate animation in this

Comment: @aryanagarwal <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    >

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%"
        />
</set>    here it is for left translate animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an ObjectAnimator for this:

```
ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(your_imageview, "translationY", 0f, 100f,0f);
                animY.setDuration(1000);//1sec
                animY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
                animY.setRepeatCount(0);
                animY.start();
```